# Wordpress filter locale and add_action->switch_to_locale

Tags: wordpress, locale, add-filter, add-action

Changing locale via `add_action->switch_to_locale` works while `add_filter` doesn't.

**add_filter**

```
function change_locale( $locale ) {
if (is_singular()) {
        global $post;
        if(($post->ID=='1839') || ($post->ID=='577') || ($post->ID=='1346')){
            $locale = 'en_US';
        }
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter('locale', 'change_locale');
```

**add_action**

```
function change_to_english_local() {
    if (is_singular()) {
        global $post;
        if(($post->ID=='1839') || ($post->ID=='577') || ($post->ID=='1346')){
            switch_to_locale('en_US');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'change_to_english_local');
```

Why?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both working on my end. `echo get_locale();` while in a loop return the modified version in both case.

Comment: I know both should work yet only `add_action` works for me....any ideas why?